Find the length of EF in the following trapezoid
While I am trying to solve the following problem: In the trapezoid $ABCD$, $AD\parallel BC$, $\angle B = 30^{\circ}$, $\angle C =60^{\circ}$. $E$, $M$, $F$, $N$ are the midpoints of $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$ respectively. Given that $BC =7$, $MN = 3$. Find $EF$.

First, I made 3 perpendiculars from A, N and D on the base BC, then I tried to make use of the two angles $\angle B = 30^{\circ}$, $\angle C =60^{\circ}$ to get the length of these perpendiculars but in vain because I don't have the length of any side from the resulting triangles! Any hint to find the length of $EF$ is appreciated.



If you extend AB to where it meets DC, what angle is formed, and can you calculate the area of that triangle?

The angle should be 90. What about the area?

Forget about the area, can you use similar triangles and the fact that in a right triangle, the median on the hypotenuse is half its length?

@DS Could you share more details please?

Try bisecting the hypotenuse of any right triangle, what relation do you find with the median to the right angle, and what does that have to do with the values of BC and NM you are given.

As RobinSparrow's comment suggests, the following is your diagram with $BA$, $CD$ and $MN$ extended to meet at $G$. Also, denote where $GM$ and $EF$ cross as $H$.

The sum of angles in $\triangle BCG$ give that $\measuredangle BGC = 90^{\circ}$. Since the line from $G$ to $M$ will, by similar triangles, bisect each line parallel to $BC$, this means that $GN$ and $GM$ are part of the same line.
DS's comment indicates that the length of $GM$ is half that of the hypotenuse, i.e., $BC$ (so, since that is $7$, then $\lvert GM\rvert = \frac{7}{2}$). There are several ways to prove this. First, since the hypotenuse is the diameter of any circumscribed circle, then $GM$ is the radius. Next, using the explicit median length formula, with $c$ being the hypotenuse and $a^2+b^2=c^2$, we get $m_c = \sqrt{\frac{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}}=\frac{c}{2}$. Finally, for this specific case of a $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$ triangle, since $\lvert GC\rvert = \frac{\lvert BC\rvert}{2}$, then $\lvert GC\rvert = \lvert MC\rvert$, so $\triangle GCM$ is isosceles. Since $\measuredangle GCM = 60^{\circ}$, then so are the other $2$ angles, which means $\triangle GCM$ is actually equilateral.
By similar triangles or other means, we have $\lvert MH\rvert = \frac{\lvert MN\rvert}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$. Thus, $\lvert GH\rvert = \frac{7}{2}-\frac{3}{2} = 2$. Since $EF$ is the hypotenuse of $\triangle EFG$, then its length is double that, i.e., it's $4$. Alternatively, since $\triangle EFG \sim \triangle BCG$, we also get that
$$\frac{\lvert EF\rvert}{\lvert BC\rvert} = \frac{\lvert GH\rvert}{\lvert GM\rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{\lvert EF\rvert}{7} = \frac{2}{\frac{7}{2}} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert EF\rvert = 4$$
On a side note, with $\triangle ADG$, as $\lvert GN\rvert = \frac{7}{2} - 3 = \frac{1}{2}$, then $\lvert AD\rvert = 1$. However, the diagram shows $\lvert AD\rvert$ as being about half of $\lvert BC\rvert$, i.e., it appears to be roughly $3$ or $4$ instead.
